# Google Cloud Messaging is not working on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, google-cloud-messaging

For sending notifications I'm using Google Cloud Messaging. GCM is not working on iPhone Development environment. I am not able to receive notification & I keep getting this error message:

```
{
    "multicast_id":7853822831817905743,
    "success":0,
    "failure":1,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[
        {
            "error":"InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this fixed it for me:

In xcode, select your target and, under the "capabilities" tab,
   enable push notifications. xCode will then report that it has added
   the push notification entitlement to your app id.

At this point you should no longer receive the `"error":"InvalidRegistration"` error anymore.

Still, if you are not receiving notifications sent through GCM, try specifying the high
   priority (`"priority": "high"` at the root of your json payload.)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was multiple Provision Profiles with the same name.

I had old Certificates already added to KeyChainAccess. So i cleared all previous profiles & added again.